# TSC does not work in docker image but in normal environment

Tags: typescript, docker

I've got a express project written in typescript. The building process works just fine in my normal environment (on like every desktop) but not in docker. If I try running the `tsc` command within the image a error gets thrown.

`error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file '/var/server/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["lib/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["node_modules"]'.`

Folder structure

```
userservice/
├── lib/
   ├── somefile.ts
   ├── file.ts
   ├── otherfile.ts
   ├── samplefile.ts
   └── controller
       └── mvcController1.ts
       └── mvcController2.ts
├── tsconfig.ts
├── otherfiles
```

I already tried

- changing the first item of the `include` array from `"lib/**/*.ts"` to `"**/*.ts"`

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./lib"
    },
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

```
FROM mongo-express

# Copying Dist Files to /var/server
COPY ./ /var/server

# Changing workdir to /var/server
WORKDIR /var/server

# Installing Necessary Packages 
RUN npm i
RUN npm run lint
RUN npm run build

# Expose Port
EXPOSE 80

# Running in production
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "./dist/server.js" ]
```

I want the docker container to run the `tsc` command the same way as in normal environment. And don't want the exception to be thrown.

Comment: You should include your dockerfile in the question details

Comment: Added. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh... The `lib/` directory was a part of the .dockerignore file...
I'm sorry for wasting your time. Nethertheless many thanks to everyone who read this question!